# How can i get my all file that i am the owner from my google drive using google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to gell all my files from my google drive but errors show "GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.patch failed with error: Only the owner or an organizer can modify the restricted label". I tried to search this problem but no result i found. I tried also to get my file if(file.getOwner().getEmail() == email) but this one not working as well.

```
var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  // Log the name of every file in the user's Drive.
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileID = file.getId();
    Drive.Files.patch({copyRequiresWriterPermission:true}, fileID);
  }
```

Another way i tried:

```
var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  // Log the name of every file in the user's Drive.
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileID = file.getId();
    if(email == file.getOnwer().getEmail()){
      Drive.Files.patch({copyRequiresWriterPermission:true}, fileID);
    }
  }
```

Comment: It seems the file your are trying to modify is restricted. Do you permission to modify it ?

Comment: That why im looking for a solution to modify only my files except files that shared to me

Answer (score 0):

The error in your first code is because you're trying to modify a file which you don't have owner or manager permission.

Your second code works for almost all files less for the ones that are inside a shared drive. Because as stated in the description of the owner attribute in the Drive API documentation for the File object [1], it will not be populated for a file in a shared drive, so you are getting a null. To avoid this, I added another condition to avoid files with null owner.

```
function test2() {
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileID = file.getId();
    var owner = file.getOwner();

    if (owner != null) {
      if(email == owner.getEmail()){
        Drive.Files.patch({copyRequiresWriterPermission:false}, fileID);
      }
    }    
  }
}
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files